# C# Lambda / extension methods flatten results between 4 entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I have a `Tag` entity in EF6 that has a one-to-many relationship to 3 other entities:

```
              Tag
          /    |      \
Definition   Variant   Machine  

Tag
{
    Id : 1,
    Name : New York,
    Definition
    {
        Id : 1,
        Title: EquipA
    },
    Definition
    {
        Id : 2,
        Title: EquipB
    },
    Variant
    {
        Id : 1,
        Name: EquipA11
    },
    Variant
    {
        Id : 2,
        Name: EquipB11
    },
    Machine
    {
        Id : 1,
        Plant : New York,
        Line : 1A
    }
    Machine
    {
        Id : 2,
        Plant : New York,
        Line : 2B
    }
}
```

I want to return the flattened results for all 4 entities so I get results like this:

```
Tag.Id, Tag.Name, Tag.Definition.Id, Tag.Definition.Title, Tag.Variant.Id, Tag.Variant.Name, Tag.Machine.Id, Tag.Machine.Plant, Tag.Machine.Line

1, New York, 1, EquipA, 1, EquipA11, 1, New York, 1A
1, New York, 1, EquipA, 1, EquipA11, 2, New York, 2B
1, New York, 1, EquipA, 2, EquipB11, 1, New York, 1A
1, New York, 1, EquipA, 2, EquipB11, 2, New York, 2B
1, New York, 2, EquipB, 1, EquipA11, 1, New York, 1A
1, New York, 2, EquipB, 1, EquipA11, 2, New York, 2B
1, New York, 2, EquipB, 2, EquipB11, 1, New York, 1A
1, New York, 2, EquipB, 2, EquipB11, 2, New York, 2B
```

I am able to do this, but I can only get the Definitions, not sure how to select from all 4 entities:

```
var temp = db.Tags.Include(c => c.Definition)
              .Include(v => v.Variant)
              .Include(p => p.PaperMachine)
              .SelectMany(t => t.Definition)
              .Select(t => new { t.Id, t.Title } )
              //.SelectMany(c => c.Definition, v => v.Variant,  )
              //.SelectMany(v => v.)
              .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to produce a Cartesian across all of the associated entities.

Something like this should net the results you are looking for:

```
var temp = db.Tags
    .SelectMany(t => t.Definitions
        .SelectMany(d => d.Tag.Variants
            .SelectMany(v => v.Tag.PaperMachines
                .Select(p => new 
                {
                   TagId = t.Id, 
                   TagName = t.Name,
                   DefinitionId = d.Id,
                   DefinitionName = d.Name,
                   VariantId = v.Id,
                   VariantName = v.Name,
                   PaperMachineId = p.Id,
                   PaperMachineName = p.Name
                })))).ToList();
```

This populates an anonymous type with the requested details. You can define a DTO/ViewModel to populate and return if this needs to go back to a caller/view. This requires bi-directional navigation properties to get from the tag to each child and back to the tag. Alternatively you could use `Join` though I suspect that will be a bit messier to read.

There may be a more succinct way to get it. Normally I'm helping people avoid Cartesians, not purposefully making them. :)

Edit: For a many-to-many relationship you can use the above query without the reverse navigation property...

```
var temp = db.Tags
    .SelectMany(t => t.Definitions
        .SelectMany(d => t.Variants
            .SelectMany(v => t.PaperMachines
                .Select(p => new 
                {
                   TagId = t.Id, 
                   TagName = t.Name,
                   DefinitionId = d.Id,
                   DefinitionName = d.Name,
                   VariantId = v.Id,
                   VariantName = v.Name,
                   PaperMachineId = p.Id,
                   PaperMachineName = p.Name
                })))).ToList();
```

This looks a bit weird, but does appear to do the trick. Note that for the `SelectMany` joins we join back in on the `t.` references, but this allows us to still join across combinations of our (t)ag, (d)efinition, (v)ariant, and (p)aperMachine reference in the final Select.

Be cautious because this will get exponentially bigger and more expensive with the more combinations you introduce.

Comment: Intellisense wont let me do: var temp = db.Tags
    .SelectMany(t => t.Definitions
        .SelectMany(d => d.Tags.Variants -- it will only let me do:  var temp = db.Tags
    .SelectMany(t => t.Definitions
        .SelectMany(d => d.Tag.FirstOrDefault().Variants -- I thought multiple selectMany were only for nested entities, not sibling entities

Comment: No, it can be used across siblings. Your error would be due to a many-to-many relationship between tag and variant. My example was assuming a 1-to-many. (tag has variants, a variant back to tag) I'll add an edit to the solution because it can still work with a many-to-many...